What does ‘a grade-hog’ mean?
I would like to know the meaning of a grade-hog in this New York Times quotation about How We Learn by Benedict Carey:

Carey, a New York Times science reporter, begins his book with a confession: He once was a grind. Like those high-school students in South Korea, he was “the kid who sweated the details, who made flashcards. A striver, a grade-hog, a worker bee.”


That's not a sentence. The meaning seems clear from the other two phrases, but please give a bit more context if you can. If you're unclear on the other two phrases, please look up "strive" and "worker bee" in a dictionary and edit to tell what you found and what questions remain.

It's not a usage I've ever seen before. I would guess that a "grade-hog" would try to edge out other students for a good grade.

If you cannot find the answer by referring to a dictionary or similar reference, you will need to provide more context about where you found this.

Does your current level of English experience allow you to guess whether this compound word is talking about a grader of hogs or about a hogger of grades?

@AndyBonner Added the full context.

Actually grade-hog is a oxymoron and a slur. Should students condemn one the studious student? Does a student getting a good grade prevent others from doing so?

@Xanne I assume you're not really asking, right?  You're not familiar with "breaking the curve" and the repercussions a student might face for getting a good/the best grade?  But anyone can be an anything-hog, is it a slur or just an extreme? I can see it as a pun grade A hog.   Anywhoomp.

Well, true, breaking the curve is bad.

The book name is : how we learn , benedict carey . any comments about author and book ?

Breaking the curve is bad? Rather, being lazy, and relying on others to be lazy in order to make one's own grades look better, and then blaming them if they make good use of their schooling years, is bad.

This is related to the following sense of "hog" from M-W

3 a: a selfish, gluttonous, or filthy person
b: one that uses something to excess
old cars that are gas hogs

So it means someone who goes to extreme lengths (e.g. making flash cards for memorizing facts) to earn good grades. The rest of the quoted text makes it clear that the author is characterizing himself as an overachiever -- he's just trying to get good grades for himself, not trying to take anything away from others.

Flash cards aren't extreme lengths, they are a legitmate memorization aid

@NoName Back when I was in high school, "legitimate memorization aids" were considered going to extreme lenghts by the cool boys. Reading the book multiple times and maybe having a classmate explain it to you and half-assing the test was what was considered the baseline. Having to actually work by writing the information that was already in the book was too much effort already for the average student.

A part of the concept that should probably be emphasised is that the student is motivated by the grades (and, perhaps, similar rewards that are external to the knowledge itself), rather than by the intrinsic value of the knowledge.

Reading the book multiple times never occurred to me!

@Zachiel - my son's classes term for that type of behaviour was 'being a keeno'.

@NoName If most students don't do it, it's extreme.

Here the term "hog" is used with the specific pejorative meaning of collecting something but also excluding others from having it. It isn't just saying the person covets grades (as the term grade grubber would), its also to imply they annoy/directly disadvantage other people when they do it. E.g. someone who hogs all the pizza (leaving others with no pizza and therefore angry/annoyed at the hogger) as opposed to an inefficient gas-hog car which doesn't stop others from getting gas. This answer misses the disadvantaging of others part and needs to mention the "ruining the grading curve" aspect.

@Esco I don't think they're preventing anyone else, they're just trying to get the best grades for themselves. He's describing himself as obsessive about grades. Consider the kids who win spelling bees, by spending much of their leisure time reading dictionaries and having their family quiz them.

It's similar in meaning to a grade grubber.
The Urban Dictionary show the top result for grade grubber as:

Someone who feels the need to have a better score than anyone else in
the known (and perhaps unknown) universe. If someone gets a higher
score, the grade grubber seeks an immediate answer to the question of
why s/he does not have the highest, bestest, prettiest score, most
colorful star, or brightest happy face sticker, and thus proceeds to
not shut up about it for 12 days until the next grade issue arises.

Likewise, from the article "Why You Should Not Engage in Grade Grubbing":

Grade Grubbing (also called "grade begging" or "grade lawyering") is
the act of a student going to a professor and asking for a grade to be
raised for no legitimate reason. Often the student argues that they
feel their work was "not graded fairly", or they made only a small
mistake and should get more points, or they knew what they were doing
even though they gave the wrong answer. Grade grubbing often involves
asking for detailed justification of why certain points were taken
off, questioning subjective aspects of grading (e.g., Why is this
problem worth 5 points and this one worth 7 points?), and wearing down
the professor by arguing, begging, and pleading until they finally
relent and increase the student's grade.


A 'grade-hog' is someone who achieves a marking score that is so high that it prevents the tutor from artificially inflating other student's grades to match a normal distribution.

The theory is that a very sharp student who aces an exam that everyone
else has trouble with will "throw off the curve." For example, if the
majority of testers earned a 70% and only one student in the whole
class earned an A, a 98%, then when the teacher goes to adjust the
grades, that outlier could make it harder for other students to score
higher.
Thoughtco - Grading on a curve

If I get 100% on a test by studying far harder than would normally be expected, it prevents other students from being given extra marks to inflate their grades (since I would have now have a score of more than 100%), so everyone has to stay with their original lower grades.
I have literally hogged, that is to say selfishly taken, the highest grade.

This doesn't seem to be what the quote is describ ing when it says "A striver, a grade-hog, a worker bee." It's just someone who treies really hard to get good grades.

@Barmar - Hogging means to unjustly and selfishly garner unto oneself. You "hog" the limelight from others.

I think the "gas hog" example from the definition I quoted may be more on point. If my car is a gas hog, it's not preventing other people from getting gas. If you're a food hog, you just eat an excessive amount of food, but you're not generally taking from someone else.

@Barmar - In both instances you're hogging the gas, that is to say, taking more than your fair share. Think road-hog or hogging the buffet.

And I don't think that's the analogy here. Grades aren't a zero-sum game. If I get a perfect score on a test, it doesn't prevent other students from doing the same.

And unless there's a gas shortage, gas hogs don't take anything away from others. Everyone can get all the gas they need.

@Barmar, this may not may not be the case, depending in whether the grading is 'on a curve'. But even if the grading is not on a curve, the grades often play a role in competitive pursuits (such as obtaining employment or admission to further education), and one's grades thus do affect the value of the grades of others.

@jsw29 He's talking about his general approach to studying, not any particular class. They won't all be on a curve.

Read the entire passage, don't focus on just this one word. Context matters.

I think that this definition adds unnecessary elements, like the assumption that an educator would inflate the grades to meet some sort of acceptable grade range.  Maybe I was just in an odd place, but I can assure you that there are professors that won't do this.  They are rare, but they have tenure, and are completely happy with the majority of their class getting C's (or dropping the class prior to the drop deadline).  I prefer the "glutton" interpretation of "hog" not some sort of "breaks grade inflation" interpertation.

@Barmar - In the US, grading on a curve and inflating grades is incredibly common.

@Richard Perhaps. But I still don't think that someone calling themselves a grade-hog is admitting that their goal was to break the curve. They're just saying they're an overachiever in scholastics. He compares himself to S. Korean students, who are all expected by their parents to excel -- you can't all break the curve.

Grade hogger would presumably mean a student who tries excessively hard to get good grades, it's similar to phrases like "goodie-two-shoes" and "teachers pet", referring to students who follow all the rules by the book, do everything they can to curry favor with their teachers and the school administration, spend long nights cramming for tests and doing their homework, who are smart enough to know the answers but unintelligent (or intelligent) enough to be extremely obedient and docile, for whom even an ounce of trouble at school is completely alien, and who avoid partying like the plague.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
